# Getting Strange Output in Reverse Geo coder in iphone dev

Tags: iphone, mapkit

I am working on map kit and i have task to change location in mapkit using `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` class, i always successfully get latitude and longitude but i couldn't get location some time. I am doing like this.

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;  //user must press for 2 seconds
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release]; 



 - (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
pa.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
temp.latitude= pa.coordinate.latitude;
temp.longitude= pa.coordinate.longitude;
 MKReverseGeocoder *reverseGeocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:pa.coordinate];
reverseGeocoder.delegate = self;
[reverseGeocoder start];


}
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFindPlacemark:(MKPlacemark *)placemark
{
temp.location = ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placemark.addressDictionary, NO);
NSLog(@"original location is %@",temp.location);

}
```

But some time i got error like this

> /SourceCache/ProtocolBuffer/ProtocolBuffer-92/Runtime/PBRequester.m:687
>   server returned error: 503 2012-01-02 16:19:36.284 openInvite[303:707]
>   reverseGeocoder: didFailWithError:Error
>   Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1011 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1011.)" UserInfo=0x124ea0
>   {PBHTTPStatusCode=503}

Please help me on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP Status Code is the clue.

> 503 Service Unavailable
>
> The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a
>   temporary overloading or maintenance of the server. The implication is
>   that this is a temporary condition which will be alleviated after some
>   delay. If known, the length of the delay MAY be indicated in a
>   Retry-After header. If no Retry-After is given, the client SHOULD
>   handle the response as it would for a 500 response.
>
> ```
>   Note: The existence of the 503 status code does not imply that a
>   server must use it when becoming overloaded. Some servers may wish
>   to simply refuse the connection.
> ```

So check the HTTP Status code and if its 503 send the Request again. This should fix the problem

Comment: is this best approach to try again and again, because i am going to upload my app onto itunes, so how can resolve this problem permanently?

Comment: If the Server is refusing the connection you have no other Possibility as to try it again. Surely you shouldnt do that infinite, so you also should implement a limit to the Number of Requests.