# Verify CLPlaceMark is within the United States

Tags: objective-c, core-location

I need to verify that users of my app are within the US. Currently I get their GPS location or, if they will not share their GPS location, I ask for a zip code. In both cases I use the CLGeocoder class to ask to get the CLPlaceMark for the location (via reverse or forward geocoding).

How can I use the CLPlaceMark to verify that they are within the United States?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To verify that users are within the US for my app, I decided to use a string comparison to CLPlaceMark's country property.

```
CLPlacemark *placemark = nil;

for (CLPlacemark *extractedPlacemark in placemarks) {
    if ([extractedPlacemark.country isEqualToString:@"United States"]) {
            placemark = extractedPlacemark;
    }
}

if (place mark) {
    // Do something with place mark because its within the United States
} else {
    // Let the user know that they must be within the United States to use the app
}
```

Its probably not the best solution since its a string comparison, but I could not find a better solution.

Comment: A better solution should be check the CountryCode. Country is a literal which I guess it will be localized.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to reverse geocode their location. To do that, look into the [CLGeocoder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder) class.

I also think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8705741/27860) might be useful.

Comment: I'm already using reverse and forward geocoding to get the CLPlaceMark. I need to know the best way to verify that the CLPlaceMark is within the United States. Right now I'm doing a raw string comparison to CLPlaceMark's country property, I need to know if there is a better way then this.