# How to get ZipCode from latitude and longitude in iOS?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am able to fetch latitude, longitude, city & address using **CLLocationManagerDelegate**. But i am unable to get ZipCode for some locations. Is there any way to get near by ZipCode using latitude and longitude?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here you go](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8705741/312312)

Comment: Can you give examples of Zips you can and can't get?  What do you mean by `some` ?

Comment: hi peter, i can't able to get zipcode for latitude: 17.427641 longitude:78.458890  it was showing null

Comment: checkout this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564852/get-zip-code-from-latitude-longitude. hope it helps :)

Comment: @user2294134 Is that 17 N or S and 78 E or W?  Are you making assumptions about the sign of the lat/long?  EG 17N 78E is in India, but 17N 78W is in the middle of the Caribbean

Comment: peter, 17N 78E  in india

Answer (score 5):

1. Create a `CLLocation` with the lat/long values you got from the `locationManagerDelegate`
2. Instantiate a `CLGeocoder` and use `- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler` [(See reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009573-CH1-SW1)
3. The completionhandler contains an NSArray `placemark`.
4. One of the properties of a CLPlacemark is `postalCode` [(See reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLPlacemark)

Answer (score 0):

if the thePlacemark.postalCode is empty, you could try to increase the horizontal accuracy of the CLLocation with:

```
– initWithCoordinate:altitude:horizontalAccuracy:verticalAccuracy:timestamp:
```