# Zip code from current location in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, zipcode

I've been googling around a little bit, but i can't seem to find code snippets that can give me the zip code of the current location from an iOS device without any use of API's and such. Most answers regarding the topic are using deprecated classes. And if this is possible, will it only get zip codes from the US or other countries in Europe aswell?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `MKReverseGeocoder` is deprecated in iOS 5, now it's `CLGeocoder`. You could create a `CLGeocoder` object and, with a previously-created `CLLocation` object with the coordinates, use the following method:

`- (void)reverseGeocodeLocation:(CLLocation *)location completionHandler:(CLGeocodeCompletionHandler)completionHandler`

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GeocoderDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011097) is an example and [Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CLGeocoder).

Comment: I can't see how that will give the current zip code. Nothing in the example mentions anything about it either. If only you could be a little bit more spesific that would be great. Hovever, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. +1 for that. :)

Comment: Well, I'm sorry about that, I'll try to be more specific: Since the completion handler gives you the following `(NSArray *placemark, NSError *error)`, all you have to do is iterate the placemarks `NSArray`, that contains a collection of `CLPlacemark` objects. Each one of them contains the postalCode attribute that you're looking for. Here you have an example, probably isn't your concrete case but  I think will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8705302/reverse-geocode-current-location